# jquery duplicate ajax request after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that opens inside a BS4 modal window. This contents of the form comes from an AJAX request and that part works fine. However, when I submit the form (again an AJAX request) and it returns some info without closing the modal, and then I submit again, it submits twice. If I submit again, it submits 3 times, etc etc, each time one more submit.

What I missing here? This is my code:

```
<div id="empModal">
  ... modal stuff here ...    
    <div id="NewCustomer" class="col-12 view">
        <div id="NewCustomerErrors"></div>
        <form name="create_account" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                ... form stuff here ...
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right mt-3"><a href="#" id="customerNewSubmit">Add new customer</a></div>
            <div class="pull-left mt-3"><a href="#" id="customerBackLogin">Back to Log In</a></div>
        </form>
    </div>
  ... modal stuff here ...
</div>
```

Part 1

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#empModal").on('click', '#customerNewSubmit', function(e) {

                $('.needs-validation').on('submit', function(e) {
                    if (!this.checkValidity()) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(this).addClass('was-validated');
                    var values = $(this).serialize();
                    doCreateAccount(values);
                });
                $('.needs-validation').submit();
                return false;
            });


        });
```

Part 2

```
function doCreateAccount(values) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_controller.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: values+'&act=new',
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res.result_success == true) {
                        $("#userButton").html(res.result_content);
                        $('#empModal').modal('hide');
                    } else {
                        $("#addNewCustomerErrors").html(res.result_content);
                    }
                },
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

from your part 1.

`$('.needs-validation').submit();`

Comment this code because this is submitting a form again after single submission.

Comment: thank you, but if I do that, it doesn't submit at all. It doesn't validate either .